# Getting a query to work on SQLite as well as on MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, sqlite

I have a subquery with a condition in the main query where clause.

Here is the sample schema

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `discount_id` int(11),
  `amount` int(11) 
);

CREATE TABLE `discounts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate` int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

And the query

```
SELECT 
  discounts.*, 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) 
   FROM payments 
   WHERE payments.discount_id = discounts.id 
   GROUP BY payments.discount_id) AS usage_count
FROM discounts   
WHERE
  rate > 10
  AND usage_count > 1
```

- Working on SQLite : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9f159/2
- Not working on MySQL : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f1593/1

MySQL shows error `Unknown column 'usage_count' in 'where clause'`

I can get it to work on MySQL using a `HAVING` clause but then it fails on SQLite with `TypeError: e.STATEMENT is undefined`

- Not working on SQLite : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9f159
- Working on MySQL : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f1593/2

Is there any way to have a single way of working with both?

Why? I am developing using the Laravel framework, our unit tests run on SQLite and the app server runs MySQL.

Comment: Now you know why it is a Bad Idea™ to use different databases for development, test, and production. You might be able to find a solution in this case, but not necessarily in other cases, and something that might work in both DBMSes won't be optimal in either.

Comment: Rare occurrences of complex queries in that project. Gain of using in-memory SQLite DB for tests is quite huge in terms of developer comfort. That's ok to sacrifice some time sometimes in order to save a lot every day. I could always use a specific test running under a dev instance of MySQL (which is done for some other tests). Just curious if I am missing some SQL concepts, that is not my strenght

Comment: You're welcome to shoot yourself in the foot in whichever way you deem most appropriate.

Comment: I don't think it's a big undertaking to install MySQL on any machine! Ghost a machine image for your devs?

Comment: or a docker container containing the database and loaded test data.

Comment: Thanks, we already have a VM with mysql and all the stuff to replicate the prod environment. My question is not about that. We have several thousands of tests (3500+) and SQLite for us is a requirement for most tests. I do understand the pros and cons of such an approach. Thanks to the two people who answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or as a join as your sub-query was only a JOIN and where was based on discounts only.

```
SELECT 
  discounts.*, count(*) as usage_count
FROM discounts   
JOIN payments
  ON payments.discount_id = discounts.id 
WHERE
  rate > 10
GROUP BY payments.discount_id
HAVING usage_count > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT 
  discounts.*, 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) 
   FROM payments 
   WHERE payments.discount_id = discounts.id 
   GROUP BY payments.discount_id) AS usage_count
FROM discounts   
WHERE rate > 10) table1 
WHERE usage_count > 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Other answer accepted as it will be easier to setup using the Eloquent ORM we use (in Laravel)